# angular ui-view nested routing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I have a  nested  ui-route in my application. The index page (root page), works, but not the nested pages.

Here is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider
        .state('index',
        {
            url: '/index',
            templateUrl: 'index.html'
        })
        .state("index.salesorder",
        {
            url: '/salesorder',
            views: {
                'mainlayout': {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/salesorder.html'

                }
            }

        });
});
```

In my index.html, I have the div with ui-view attribute

```
<div ui-view="mainlayout"> </div>
```

I have also added the necessary scripts for angular, and ui-route. I do not get any errors in the console. But the salesorder does not show. I get to see the index though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second state `index.salesorder` is a child state of `index`. Do you have the ui-view nested correctly? It looks like you might need 3 levels of ui-views.

try this:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $stateProvider
        .state("salesorder",
        {
            url: '/salesorder',
            views: {
                'mainlayout': {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/salesorder.html'

                }
            }

        });
});
```

main.html:

```html
<div ui-view></div>
```

salesorder.html:

```html
<div ui-view="mainlayout"></div>
```

Comment: dannielum . I have got it working, with a slight change to your answer. I have left the mainlayout within index page itself and it works now. Thank you